# How to remember these probability results?

Tags: probability

If $A,B$ and $C$ are  $3$ events, then

1. $P$(Exactly one of $A,B,C$ occurs)$=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-2[P(A \cap B)+P(B \cap C)+P(A \cap C)]+3P(A \cap B \cap C)$
2. $P$(Exactly two of $A,B,C$ occur)$=P(A \cap B)+P(B \cap C)+P(A \cap C)-3P(A \cap B \cap C)$
3. $P$(At least two of $A,B,C$ occur)$=P(A \cap B)+P(B \cap C)+P(A \cap C)-2P(A \cap B \cap C)$

Comment: Here is how I remember them: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151635/generalizing-the-total-probability-of-simultaneous-occurrences-for-independent-e/163735#163735

Comment: yeah, should be $-2P(A\cap B\cap C)$

Comment: @Henry Thankx Done editing.

Comment: @Giovanni Thankx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A picture is worth a thousand words

[image]

Comment: What you have labelled as $A\cap B$ should really be $A\cap B\cap \bar{C}$ and similarly for the two other regions

Comment: Hi David, I am sorry but I really don't understand your comment. I don't think that the closure of a set has any meaning in this context, so I guess you meant the complement of $C$. If that is the case I am pretty sure that whoever did this (I took it from wikipedia) wanted the whole intersection of $A$ and $B$ there.Of course it includes the part where they all intersect, but this is fairly obvious :) Please, let me know if I misunderstood your comment

Comment: Yes I mean the complement of C. $A\cap B$ should include $A\cap B\cap C$

Comment: As I said, it does contain the triple intersection.